# daemonset doesn't create any pod which need hostpath access with namesapce at enforce=baseline level

Tags: kubernetes, security-context, daemonset, podsecuritypolicy

We are testing pod security where product namesapce level enforce=baseline, in that case fluent-bit pods were not starting, They are failing with below message.

We are testing pod security where product namesapce level enforce=baseline, in that case fluent-bit pods were not starting, They are failing with below message.

Error message:
Warning  FailedCreate  4m2s   daemonset-controller  Error creating: pods "objectscale-manager-fluent-bit-96rq4" is forbidden: violates PodSecurity "baseline:latest": hostPath volumes (volumes "varlog", "varlibdockercontainers")

I am interested to know is it possible to achieve rolebinding/clusterrolebinding or other ways to run daemonset pods by keeping namesapce at enforce=baseline level & mounting hostpath.

k8s version - GitVersion:v1.25.4+a34b9e9
kubectl version - GitVersion:v1.25.2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.